# Stream Raw audio file using Howler.js

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, wav, audio-streaming, howler.js

I am able to play audio in Howler.js from bbc radio with following code snippet. But, I have raw audio data in mylocal server which does not contain a specific header. How can I stream these raw data?

```
var soundbbc = new Howl({
        src: 'http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_q',
        html5: true, // A live stream can only be played through HTML5 Audio.
        format: ['wav']
    });
```